# GIT - Get CruiseControl NET to Push to Origin

Tags: git, cruisecontrol.net

I have go CruiseControl.NET successfully building my solution.  Before it builds, it increments the version number in a shared "assemblyinfo.cs" - I wrote a custom command-line util to do this.

My project is setup as follows:

```
<sourcecontrol type="git">
    <repository>git@source-server.com:repo.git</repository>
    <branch>develop</branch>
    <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
    <fetchSubmodules>true</fetchSubmodules>
    <tagOnSuccess>true</tagOnSuccess>
    <commitBuildModifications>true</commitBuildModifications>
    <commitUntrackedFiles>false</commitUntrackedFiles>
    <tagCommitMessage>Auto Build {0}</tagCommitMessage>
    <tagNameFormat>Auto-Build-{0}</tagNameFormat>
    <committerName>Build Server</committerName>
    <committerEMail>test@test.com</committerEMail>
    <workingDirectory>C:\Scratch\repo</workingDirectory>
    <timeout units="hours">2</timeout>
</sourcecontrol>

<tasks>
  <exec>
    <!-- Custom version incrementor -->
    <executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\VersionIncrementor.exe</executable>
    <buildArgs>C:\Scratch\repo\SharedAssemblyInfo.cs</buildArgs>
    <description>Increment Version</description>
  </exec>

  <devenv>
    <solutionfile>C:\Scratch\repo\test.sln</solutionfile>
    <configuration>Debug</configuration>
    <executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com</executable>
  </devenv>

</tasks>

<publishers>
  <xmllogger />
  <artifactcleanup cleanUpMethod="KeepLastXBuilds"
                   cleanUpValue="10" />
</publishers>
```

So far, it is commit the incremented version locally, but how do I get it to push that commit to origin?

**UPDATE**

My changes are getting committed, they just aren't getting pushed.  When I open up the repo on the build machine in SourceTree see that it is "detached from origin/develop", I also see that the version is getting incremented and the commit is getting tagged, but the commit is not in my branch.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have `commitBuildModifications` and `tagOnSuccess` turned on, so any changes would be committed during the 'publish' of the build. There would be no need to change your configuration.

1. The change would only be committed in the event of a successful build
2. The change would be committed after the build, not before
3. If any of the following tasks fail the change/increment would not be committed.

See the **Tagging a successful build** section
http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Git

Comment: I do have commitBuildModifications and tagOnSuccess true, and it looks like the incremented version is getting committed and tagged locally, but its just not getting pushed...  I have attached a screenshot of source tree to help explain my problem...

Comment: @Jeeve Take a look at the source: https://github.com/ccnet/CruiseControl.NET/blob/master/project/core/sourcecontrol/Git.cs#L366 .. there is a push. Maybe its missing some saved credentials? I'm using push over ssh with shared key.